# how to add if condition (string match) in fragments (Android)

Tags: android, if-statement, android-fragments, conditional-statements

I have a login page, which on correct entry leads me to a page(dashboardactivity.java) with a one time passord(OTP) and a button 'proceed' to go to the home page. now i have the home page where i have used fragments. I have used sliding menu (like in facebook app).

For now i just have four options(i.e four fragment pages with respective layouts) 
now, on the click of my fourth menu, it leads me to a page to confirm the OTP which was generated before. only if the otp i type in the edittext equals the otp generated, i will be able to go to the next page.
I have managed to get the otp variable from 'dashboardactivity.java' to 'menu4_Fragment.java' using SharedPreferences.

I tried using the 'IF' condition to compare the string typed by user with the otp. i will paste my dashboardactivity and menu4_fragment files here along with their layout files.

Comment: you want to check if the two strings match?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)